# Юрий-Георгий-Егор-Жора — образование имен

Tags: словообразование, ономастика

Я часто задаюсь вопросом: а как образуются уменьшительные имена. Большинство, конечно, лежат на поверхности: Сергей-Сережа, Наталья-Наташа, Владимир-Володя. Но бывают и самые неожиданные. Например, как могло получиться столько вариантов от имени Георгий (по-гречески Йоргус)? Юрий, Егор. А уменьшительных и того больше. Вспомнить хотя бы знаменитое: "Он же Гоша, он же Гога, он же Жора". Как из Георгия или Юрия мог получиться Жора?))

Comment: > "Он же Гоша, он же Гога, он же Жора"
Я б лично стрелял любого, кто попытается так называть меня =)

Касательно происхождения, то на [википедии][1] дана вполне убедительная версия.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если быть совсем точным, то начальный звук в греческом - Г. Γεώργιος (земледелец). Это существенно для понимания появления всех вариантов.
Юрий - никак не уменьшительное от Георгий. Скорее всего их следует признать двумя самостоятельными именами, произошедшими от одного греческого. Остальные - еще туда-сюда, можно действительно условно считать уменьшительными. Церковные представления не беру в расчет, там больше традиции, чем обоснованности.
"Георгий" попало, как я понимаю, напрямую или очень коротким путем, минуя латынь. 
Для ранней же латыни звук Г был нехарактерен (он появился только после знакомства с греками), поэтому так произошло качественное изменение Г в Й, и далее - ЙО в Ю. Видимо, так появился "Юрий", при этом "греческий" вариант тоже сохранился. Впрочем, нечто подобное могло произойти и непосредственно на русской почве, каковой версии придерживается Вики. Не буду пересказывать, см. ссылку у gecube, мне интереснее остальные варианты. 
Далее, уже в русском, Георгий упростился до Егор, сочетание "ГЕО" было совершенно невозможно по тогдашней фонетике (заднеязычный Г перед гласным переднего ряда плюс зияние гласных ЕО). Произошла позиционная мена Г и Е, случай довольно редкий, но встречающийся (сравните Нахим от Анхим, Анфим).
Ну и наконец, "Жора". Видимо, из французского Жорж. Это произношение вполне соответствует французской фонетике. G перед Е читается как Ж, а само Е в этом случае не произносится.

Забыл! А венгры нас и тут переплюнули своим необычным звучанием привычных имен. Дьёрдь! Получите и распишитесь([[@gecube](/users/972/gecube)](/users/972/gecube), привет!)

Comment: В  13-м  веке  наряду  с  княжеским  именем  Юрий,  встречается  тоже  княжеское - Гюрги.  Тоже  от  Георгий,  или  у  него  другое  происхождение ?

Comment: Не знаю, я не сталкивался. Но, похоже, это просто фонетический вариант Георгия, тут Вики-версия вполне убедительна.